# Android app showing lat long in textViews

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I am trying to show the latitude and longitude on textView but it doesn't seem to be working. The lat and long will be sent via the emulator control, when I try sending the values it should display them on the textViews but it doesn't seem to work, maybe I've missed something?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

//Defining views
private EditText editTextLatitude;
private EditText editTextLongitude;
private EditText editTextTimeInserted;
LocationManager lm;
TextView lt, ln;
String provider;
Location l;
private Button buttonAdd;
private Button buttonView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing views
    editTextLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLat);
    editTextLongitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLon);
    editTextTimeInserted = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTimeInserted);

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);

    //Setting listeners to button
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
    ln = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lng);
    lt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();

    provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, false);

    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (l != null) {     //get latitude and longitude of the location
        double lng = l.getLongitude();
        double lat = l.getLatitude();
        //display on text view
        ln.setText("" + lng);
        lt.setText("" + lat);
    } else {
        ln.setText("No Provider");
        lt.setText("No Provider");
    }
}
```

Comment: stacktrace? please print

Comment: Mean, the value is not changing, when you are changing the latlng right?

Comment: yes the lng and lat textViews are not changing, they are suppose to change to whatever the lat long is on the emulator control.. @NigamPatro

Comment: At , the first time whether its showing?

Comment: @Tuks I don't think the latitude and longitude will change in emulator why do't you try a real device for this purpose.

Comment: Have you set up your LocationListener and requestLocationUpdates from the manager?

Comment: can you added `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` and make sure your device have `LOCATION_SERVICE` enable.

Comment: i do not have a real device and my assignment is due in tomorrow, is there not a way of doing it through the emulator? @nigampatro

Comment: I have the permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml. and how would i check if LOCATION_SERVICE is enabled? im running a emulator not a real device if that makes any difference? @pranay

Comment: Go to Tools>Android>Android Device manager >click on the Emulator Tab >there you can set the desired latitude and longitude for your emulator

Comment: yes thats what i mean, i have the android device monitor open and it is allowing me to send the latitude and longitude but when i press send they are not being displayed on my textView fields.. do you get what i mean? :/ @sushrita

Comment: @Tuks try this from the terminal or command prompt : 1st line :telnet localhost 5554  2nd line : geo fix <longitude> <latitude> [<altitude>]

Comment: Tukss-MacBook-Pro:~ Tuks$ telnet localhost 5554
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix -3453 5647
OK

Still nothing appears on the textViews? @sushrita

Comment: cbo:~ cbonline$ telnet localhost 5556
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix 37.422006 -122.084095
OK
@Tuks   After localhost give the device no which is on the top of the emulator

Comment: still nothing @sushrita

Comment: its weird, i have had a look at examples online which are either the same or similar but it doesnt seem to work with my project :/ @sushrita

Comment: Like @headuc said you have to implement LocationListener to have your app listen for location updates, onCreate only runs at once in the begining when you plug in the location through ddms that code in onCreate will not catch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have your activity implement LocationListener

```
implements LocationListener
```

then request locationUpdates inside your onCreate

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
```

then in your onLocationChanged method that you Override for implementing LocationListener update your textViews once you send the location

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    //display on text view
    ln.setText("" + lng);
    lt.setText("" + lat);    
}
```

Comment: Yes thats working perfectly now, thank you @JRowan :).. quick question when i implement LocationListener in my activity with my implements View.OnClickListener for my buttons it gives a error class activity must either be declared abstract implement abstract method onProviderEnabled(String)

Comment: i think its telling you to implement the rest of the methods from LocationListener, i dont think that you have to but to make your code complete you might want to, then again i could be wrong i never had that problem

Comment: Iv sorted it, it was telling me to implement the rest of the methods from LocationListener. Thank you for your help @JRowan